# How to import Python Keras Library on AWS Lambda

Tags: keras, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to deploy a Neural Network that can take a dataset and predict answers on the same. I am using AWS Lambda (PYTHON) to do the same. I understand that Keras cannot be accessed using the inline code editor. So how do I go about this? How do I upload my code to Lambda such that it supports keras?

Comment: Did you consider using AWS Sagemaker for that?

Answer (score 0):

The process is a bit lengthy. Here's an overview:

1. Launching an EC2 instance with the appropriate AMI
2. Creating a virtualenv on said instance
3. Installing Theano, Keras and h5py with pip
4. Staging python libraries and shared C++ libraries together for deployment
5. Writing a handler function
6. Creating an archive of the artifacts from steps 4 and 5
7. Deploying the archive to AWS Lambda

Then, if you need to improve Theano performance, you can deploy `gcc` to Lambda as well, so that it's able to make use of a compiler.

These steps, including the last step, [are described at length by Amazon's own Abhishek Patnia](https://becominghuman.ai/running-deep-learning-models-on-aws-lambda-cfd2f76ca048). You'll save yourself some time if you read through it first, as some of the latter steps amend what he does initially.

Answer (score 0):

use serverless framework, it allows you to deploy your lambda code and its dependencies on aws and other cloud service providers without having to deal with the environments differences (local vs aws linux)

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/examples/hello-world/python/